# How can I remove a spotlight effect from a MP4 captured from Youtube?

Tags: after-effects, video-editor, video-quality, youtube, lighting

I want to fix a youtube video by capturing it an removing the spotlight effect. its a bright spot in the middle of the frame. I captured it as an MP4. How can I fix it?

Comment: Show a screenshot.

Comment: I agree with Mulvya that a Screenshot is worth a 100 words. Failing that, see this: https://avisynth.org.ru/hotspot/hotspotavs.html - You'll need to install AVISynth and create a Mask for each Frame to eliminate it perfectly. Kind of an Inverse Vignette problem.